# How to return the column that contains the highest value

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an aggregation that I'm trying to get correct. I'm grouping the data together, and I'm looking to return the column that has the highest `PID`. I can use max, which returns the highest PID, but that doesn't return the corresponding `VALUE`.

These are the stage in my pipeline.

```
[
          '$project'=> [
            "RS_VERSION" => 1,
            "TRADE_DATE" => 1,
            "JURISDICTION" => 1,
            "DELIVERY_DATE" => 1,
            "DELIVERY_HOUR" => ['$convert'=> [ 'input'=> '$DELIVERY_HOUR', 'to'=> 'int']],
            "DELIVERY_INTERVAL" => ['$convert'=> [ 'input'=> '$DELIVERY_INTERVAL', 'to'=> 'int']],
            "DELIVERY_TIME" => 1,
            "VALUE" => 1,
            "DELIVERY_ORDER" => 1,
            "PID" => ['$convert'=> [ 'input'=> '$PID', 'to'=> 'int']],
            "KEY"=> [ 
              '$concat'=> [
                '_', '$RS_VERSION', '_', '$TRADE_DATE', '_', '$JURISDICTION', '_', '$DELIVERY_DATE', '_', '$DELIVERY_HOUR', '_', '$DELIVERY_INTERVAL' ,'_', '$DELIVERY_TIME', '_', '$DELIVERY_ORDER'
              ]
            ],
          ]
        ],
        [
          '$group'=> [
            '_id'=> '$KEY',
            'RS_VERSION'=>['$first'=> '$RS_VERSION'],
            'TRADE_DATE'=>['$first'=> '$TRADE_DATE'],
            'JURISDICTION'=>['$first'=> '$JURISDICTION'],
            'DELIVERY_DATE'=>['$first'=> '$DELIVERY_DATE'],
            'DELIVERY_HOUR' =>['$first'=> '$DELIVERY_HOUR'],
            'DELIVERY_INTERVAL' =>['$first'=> '$DELIVERY_INTERVAL'],
            'DELIVERY_TIME'=>['$first'=> '$DELIVERY_TIME'],
            'DELIVERY_ORDER'=>['$first'=> '$DELIVERY_ORDER'],
            'pid' => ['$first'=> '$PID'],
            'VALUE' => ['$first' => '$VALUE']
          ]
        ],
```

I need to return the corresponding document values from the highest pid based on the grouping. At the moment I'm not always getting the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that $group is just taking the first document for each distinct value of `$KEY`, if that is the intent, sort by pid prior to grouping, then you can just take the first document for each key.

```
{$sort: { PID: -1 }},
```

Then the group stage will pick the first value corresponding to each key, and since the documents are in descending order by pid, these fields will all correspond to the highest pid for that key.